# Linux , How do i find hypervisor IP or hostname while logged in to a Virtual Machine

Tags: unix

> what is the command which will find me the IP or hostname  while 
>   logged in to a Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0):

If the hypervisor is any good, its hostname and IP will be invisible to the guest, unless it is explicitly configured to share this information (via some sort of guest intergation tools).

THis has nothing todo with UNIX or whatever guest OS is in use - it is (and must be) a property of the hypervisor, to be invisible to the guest concerning its network configuration.